# Set fancybox height to Iframe body height

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

There are many other flows with the similar title. I have tried all the flows but none of them worked.!

Register.php has form & related js files. Once I register, the thankyou page also appears with the same height.

[image: 3d block is what i wanted.]

HTML

```
 <a class="reg-popup fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe"  href="register.php"> Register </a>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
     jQuery(".reg-popup").fancybox({                 
            fitToView        : true,
            type             : 'iframe',
            autoSize         : false,
            minWidth         : '43%',
            maxWidth         : '50%',
            maxHeight       : '90% ',           
            width            : 'auto',
            height           : 'auto',
            autoDimensions   : true, 
            html        : true,

            beforeShow: function(){
                this.width = (jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').width());
                this.height = (jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').height());                
            },                      
            'afterClose':function () {
                      window.location.reload();                   
              },
              onUpdate : { autoHeight: true},
            helpers : {
                  overlay : {closeClick: false}
            }        
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe content is on a different sub-domain/domain you will need to use postMessage so that the two can communicate. You will need access to the content that is within the iframe so that the document height can be communicated.

Comment: I guess the main question is, why are you using an iframe and not just injecting the register form?

Comment: registration form will appear in a fancybox popup. It includes iframe.

Comment: Ok, so my assumption is that you don't have control over the register form and that you haven't developed that and you are just integrating it?

Comment: No. Registration form is developed one.

Comment: Registration form is something you have developed?

Comment: In which case, then is the contents of the iframe and the parent container on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting nextSpeed and prevSpeed to 0. I'm not sure you need the brackets around here (jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').width()) but they'll do no harm.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
     jQuery(".reg-popup").fancybox({                 
        fitToView        : true,
        type             : 'iframe',
        autoSize         : false,
        minWidth         : '43%',
        maxWidth         : '50%',
        maxHeight       : '90% ',           
        width            : 'auto',
        nextSpeed: 0,                  //add this line
        prevSpeed: 0,                  //and this line
        height           : 'auto',
        autoDimensions   : true, 
        html        : true,

        beforeShow: function(){
            this.width = (jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').width());
            this.height = (jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').height());                
        },                      
        'afterClose':function () {
                  window.location.reload();                   
          },
          onUpdate : { autoHeight: true},
        helpers : {
              overlay : {closeClick: false}
        }        
     });
});
```